# Setting hashmap values from jsp to java

Tags: servlets, struts2, hashmap

I am using struts2.1 and websphere 8.5. i have requirement to map the values. so using hashmap to set the selected drop down values from jsp. my rendered code lokk like,

```
<select name="hmAttributeMapping['-1abc1']" tabindex="1" id="idattributemapping" class="drop">
    <option value="-1"
    >*Missing*</option>
    <option value="1">Test1</option>

</select>
```

when i submit the page, only this key '-1abc' is not getting into action class. other keys are available in hashmap. Is it a special case?

Comment: There are some limitation to submitted parameter names. Try removing `-` from it and see if it works.

Comment: Yes. it is working. But i the application has this value as id. I can't resist them from using it.

Comment: I can't remove the - from it. Is there any other way to escape this in coding?

Comment: Where you cannot change it? JSP, action class? Of course you can change accepted parameters pattern but that is potentially dangerous thing.